# Pycharm Toggle Sodebar Shortcut Key?

Tags: pycharm, editor

What Pycharm's Toggle Sidebar Shortcut Key?  It does not appear in the documents. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's no default shortcut, but you can assign a new one to Tool Buttons:

[image]